# How to fill the color inside the shape containing different path like curves and lines

Tags: c#, winforms

I have drawn the shape using some path segments points, the shape is drawn but color is not filled inside the shape. I have used the FillPath() method, but the color is filled in outline only .I have added the individual points in the graphicspath object like path.AddLine(), the color is filled inside the shape. whenever I have added the whole points using for loop ,the color is not filled in the shape.

Comment: Can you provide the code you have implemented so far?

Comment: You are talking about Graphics stuff, but your question contains no images to show what you mean.

Comment: Show us the code. Maybe closing the GraphicsPath (if that's what you use) will help..

Comment: GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath(); path.AddLine(); path.AddBeizer(); private void OnPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) { Pen pen=new Pen(Color.Black); e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(200, 200); Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red); e.Graphics.DrawPath(pen, path); e.Graphics.FillPath(brush, path); } I have created the shape using lines,beizer curves ,the color is applied on the path using FillPath() , but it is filled in outline only . How to fill the color inside the shape. The shape containing different path segments and intersect each other and it also closed.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have not initialized any brush (or set any brush color).
Outline is drawned with the Pen object.
Filling is done with the Brush object.

Comment: That would not run then.

Comment: GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath(); path.AddLine(); path.AddBeizer();   private void OnPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Pen pen=new Pen(Color.Black);
            e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(200, 200);  Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
            e.Graphics.DrawPath(pen, path);
            e.Graphics.FillPath(brush, path);
        }  I have created the shape using lines,beizer curves ,the color is applied on the path using FillPath() , but it is filled in outline only . How to fill the color inside the shape. I have initialized the pen and brush object

Comment: Maybe your shape is too complex to be filled (curve going up and down). Try with a simpler one, a rectangle for example, to see if your code is working.

Comment: Yes Bioukh, My shape is too complex, that only I asked. For a simple shape ,the color is filled in the region.I have drawn the shape using many lines and curves, but the color is filled in outline only. The path segments are intersect with each other.Any other idea for fill the color inside the complicated shape.

Comment: The only way is to decompose your shape in smaller shapes, but it is often not trivial.